# Events system implementation

Tags: python, object, events

How can I implement my simple events system?

And how to create event classes correctly?
I did something like this:

```
class Event():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def execute(self):
        pass


class Feed(Event):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()        
    
    def execute(self, cat):
        cat.hungry += 10


class Play(Event):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
    
    def execute(self, cat):
        cat.mood += 10
```

Answer (score 0):

No offense what you are doing is wrong. What you did is to create child classes `Feed` and `Play` from the main class `Event`. From what I understand, what you should do it to make `Feed` and `Play` methods of the class `Cat`.

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hungry=0
        self.mood=0
    def feed(self):
        self.hungry+=10
    def Play(self):
        self.mood+=10
```